# Using Httplib2 on Python Appengine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, oauth, foursquare, httplib2

Why am I getting this error when running my application which is trying to OAuth with Foursquare?

```
import httplib2
ImportError: No module named httplib2
```

I have installed httplib2 by downloading it and  $ python setup.py install on the command line as instructed [here](http://code.google.com/p/httplib2/wiki/Install)

Am I missing something? Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You will need to include the library in your project so that the App Engine runtime knows what you're importing.

From [here](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/runtime.html#Pure_Python):

> You can include other pure Python libraries with your application by putting the code in your application directory. If you make a symbolic link to a module's directory in your application directory, appcfg.py will follow the link and include the module in your app.

Comment: I've never used symbolic link; what happen when the user publishes the app? Are the symlinked libraries packed too?

Comment: @systempuntoout: yes, appcfg.py doesn't care if the modules in the application directory are symbolic links or not; it uploads them just fine.

Comment: @Wooble I am using Google App Engine Launcher, do I use terminal to create the symlinks to the httplib2 library?

Comment: @keith: yes, `ln -s` creates symbolic links.  I'm not sure if aliases created in the Finder will work the same with dev_appserver.  I suspect they might, although I'm not at a Mac to test it at the moment.

Answer (score 3):

I've created a simple example on how to do this when using Google App Engine. (https://github.com/muanis/foursquare-oauth-bootstrap) basically you need Google oAuth2 Client (http://code.google.com/p/google-api-python-client/) and httplib2 (http://code.google.com/p/httplib2/)

Answer (score 2):

Add `httplib2` as a third party library as documented here:

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/libraries27#vendoring

Install with:

```
pip install -t lib httplib2
```

Answer (score 0):

https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/start/installation

> To install the library and all of its dependencies in an App Engine
>   project,  download the file named google-api-python-client-gae-N.M.zip
>   from the list of downloads, where N.M is the version number of the
>   latest release. Unzip that file into your project.