# How do I properly install httplib2 on Google App Engine?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, httplib2

I copied my httplib2 directory into my GAE project, and now I'm getting the following error:

```
line 64, in <module> _ssl_wrap_socket = ssl.wrap_socket
```

Is this an issue with Google App Engine, or did I somehow install my httplib2 incorrectly?

Full error dump, as request(it's big!):

```
--> --> -->
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\dev_appserver.py", line 4053, in _HandleRequest
    self._Dispatch(dispatcher, self.rfile, outfile, env_dict)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\dev_appserver.py", line 3977, in _Dispatch
    base_env_dict=env_dict)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\dev_appserver.py", line 588, in Dispatch
    base_env_dict=base_env_dict)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\dev_appserver.py", line 3050, in Dispatch
    self._module_dict)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\dev_appserver.py", line 2954, in ExecuteCGI
    reset_modules = exec_script(handler_path, cgi_path, hook)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\dev_appserver.py", line 2834, in ExecuteOrImportScript
    exec module_code in script_module.__dict__
  File "C:\Users\quaunaut\Documents\Aptana Studio 3 Workspace\qushoutout\src\main.py", line 25, in <module>
    import twitter as twitter
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\dev_appserver.py", line 1505, in Decorate
    return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\dev_appserver.py", line 2450, in load_module
    return self.FindAndLoadModule(submodule, fullname, search_path)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\dev_appserver.py", line 1505, in Decorate
    return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\dev_appserver.py", line 2339, in FindAndLoadModule
    description)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\dev_appserver.py", line 1505, in Decorate
    return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\dev_appserver.py", line 2282, in LoadModuleRestricted
    description)
  File "C:\Users\quaunaut\Documents\Aptana Studio 3 Workspace\qushoutout\src\twitter.py", line 65, in <module>
    import oauth2 as oauth
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\dev_appserver.py", line 1505, in Decorate
    return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\dev_appserver.py", line 2450, in load_module
    return self.FindAndLoadModule(submodule, fullname, search_path)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\dev_appserver.py", line 1505, in Decorate
    return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\dev_appserver.py", line 2339, in FindAndLoadModule
    description)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\dev_appserver.py", line 1505, in Decorate
    return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\dev_appserver.py", line 2282, in LoadModuleRestricted
    description)
  File "C:\Users\quaunaut\Documents\Aptana Studio 3 Workspace\qushoutout\src\oauth2\__init__.py", line 32, in <module>
    import httplib2
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\dev_appserver.py", line 1505, in Decorate
    return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\dev_appserver.py", line 2450, in load_module
    return self.FindAndLoadModule(submodule, fullname, search_path)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\dev_appserver.py", line 1505, in Decorate
    return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\dev_appserver.py", line 2339, in FindAndLoadModule
    description)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\dev_appserver.py", line 1505, in Decorate
    return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\dev_appserver.py", line 2282, in LoadModuleRestricted
    description)
  File "C:\Users\quaunaut\Documents\Aptana Studio 3 Workspace\qushoutout\src\httplib2\__init__.py", line 64, in <module>
    _ssl_wrap_socket = ssl.wrap_socket
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'wrap_socket'
```

Still having this issue. About the only thing I can think of that could possibly be causing this is my machine running Python 2.7; Is it possible that is causing the issue?

Comment: Can you show the full error dump?

Answer (score 4):

As a workaround:

Can you use Google App Engine SDK 1.4.3 (this looks like a 1.5.0 regression).

Or force httplib2 fallback on httplib.FakeSocket with:

```
import sys
sys.modules['ssl'] = None
import httplib2
```

A new issue has been filled there:
http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=5064

It looks already fixed in httplib2 side:
http://code.google.com/p/httplib2/source/detail?r=cf721c1693a68e9438899be3d78acccae6ab0e30#

Answer (score 2):

The AppEngine sandbox doesn't allow access to a sockets API, for an http library to work on GAE it would have to wrap urllib (which in turn wraps the url_fetch API).

**EDIT** Looks like httplib2 *should* work so I guess you just need to ensure your paths are setup correctly.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5056719/using-httplib2-on-python-appengine)

Comment: How do I ensure the paths are set up correctly? I'm guessing I have to make a symbolic link, but I have no idea how to do that on a Windows machine.

Comment: Do you have SSL support installed for your Python (just try `import ssl` from a the python repl? Have you named your one of your files ssl.py?

Comment: @Chris Farmiloe None of my files are called ssl.py, and importing ssl in the interpreter works without error.

Comment: @quaunaut Don't do anything special - don't install httplib2 in your app, and don't change the paths. It should work fine already.

Comment: @Nick Johnson Then care to tell me what to do to resolve my error? Because it certainly isn't working.

Comment: @quaunaut What error? The only one you've pasted is as a result of you trying to import your own copy of httplib2.

Comment: @Nick Johnson I'm not importing it, python-oauth2 is importing it in. It works fine on my system outside of a GAE environment, but inside of it, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

This [Blog](http://bitworking.org/news/406/app-engine-and-httplib2) claims to fix the GAE issues. I haven't tried it yet, but sounds right.