# google-app-engine : ImportError httplib2 in google api python client hello world

Tags: python, google-app-engine, importerror, httplib2, google-api-python-client

I just downloaded the Google App Engine SDK for python (google_appengine_1.6.5.zip) and i try to launch an example from google-api-python-client ([appengine](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-python-client/source/browse/#hg%2Fsamples%2Fappengine)) :

```
$ tree
.
|-- app.yaml
|-- client_secrets.json
|-- grant.html
|-- index.yaml
|-- main.py
`-- welcome.html
```

I launch dev server : : `./dev_appserver.py /home/yoyo/dev/projets/yoyocontacts/ --backends --clear_datastore --high_replication`

But when i launched application in my browser, i have the following error : `ImportError: No module named httplib2`.

My plateform is Ubuntu 10.04.4 LTS with Python 2.6.5 and an import of httplib2 with Python cli works fine. And there is httplib2 in google-appengine directory :

```
$ locate httplib2|grep appengine

/home/yoyo/dev/outils/google_appengine/lib/httplib2
/home/yoyo/dev/outils/google_appengine/lib/httplib2/httplib2
/home/yoyo/dev/outils/google_appengine/lib/httplib2/httplib2/LICENSE
/home/yoyo/dev/outils/google_appengine/lib/httplib2/httplib2/OWNERS
/home/yoyo/dev/outils/google_appengine/lib/httplib2/httplib2/__init__.py
...
```

How resolve properly this import problem ?

I know that i can add httplib2 in my application directory but it's not elegant :

```
$tree
...
|-- httplib2
|   |-- cacerts.txt
|   |-- __init__.py
|   |-- __init__.pyc
|   |-- iri2uri.py
|   |-- iri2uri.pyc
|   |-- socks.py
|   |-- socks.pyc
```

I finally added the correct symlinks : (thanks to @Thanasis)

```
$ll
total 36K
lrwxrwxrwx 1 yoyo   77 2012-05-06 16:24 apiclient -> /home/yoyo/dev/outils/google_appengine/lib/google-api-python-client/apiclient/
-rw-r--r-- 1 yoyo  267 2012-05-07 12:28 app.yaml
-rw-r--r-- 1 yoyo  358 2012-05-06 15:20 client_secrets.json
lrwxrwxrwx 1 yoyo   60 2012-05-07 12:12 gflags -> /usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/python_gflags-2.0-py2.5.egg
-rw-r--r-- 1 yoyo  554 2012-03-02 20:00 grant.html
lrwxrwxrwx 1 yoyo   60 2012-05-06 16:20 httplib2 -> /home/yoyo/dev/outils/google_appengine/lib/httplib2/httplib2/
-rw-r--r-- 1 yoyo  471 2012-03-02 20:00 index.yaml
-rw-r--r-- 1 yoyo 3,4K 2012-05-07 11:45 main.py
lrwxrwxrwx 1 yoyo   56 2012-05-06 16:24 oauth2 -> /home/yoyo/dev/outils/google_appengine/lib/oauth2/oauth2/
lrwxrwxrwx 1 yoyo   80 2012-05-07 10:59 oauth2client -> /home/yoyo/dev/outils/google_appengine/lib/google-api-python-client/oauth2client/
-rwxr-xr-x 1 yoyo  163 2012-05-07 11:14 run*
drwxr-xr-x 3 yoyo 4,0K 2012-05-07 12:27 static/
-rwxr-xr-x 1 yoyo  115 2012-05-07 11:50 upload*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 yoyo   79 2012-05-06 16:24 uritemplate -> /home/yoyo/dev/outils/google_appengine/lib/google-api-python-client/uritemplate/
-rw-r--r-- 1 yoyo  102 2012-03-02 20:00 welcome.html
```

Now, i have to deal with a new problem [with gflags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10480390/google-app-engine-import-works-only-after-a-refresh).

Comment: maybe duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5056719/using-httplib2-on-python-appengine

Comment: @ThanasisPetsas Yes, but the explanations are not very clear.

Comment: You'd have to add the whole httplib2 to your project, not just a link. Be sure to test first. This is now a duplicate of your other question, re-phrase or remove it?

Comment: @JonasByström I added the whole httplib2 : [http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk%2Fpython%2Flib%2Fhttplib2%2Fhttplib2%253Fstate%253Dclosed](See AppEngine source). And it's works with httplib2. I use the same method with gflags egg and it doesn't work. So it's a different problem.

Answer (score 1):

here is a solution.

- make a temporary directory somewhere out of the source tree.
- cd to the directory and unzip /usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/python_gflags-2.0-py2.5.egg
- copy *.py to the source directory.

Answer (score 0):

Most third party libraries need to be included as part of your project. The easiest way to do this (Adapted from [the App Engine documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/using-libraries-python-27#installing_a_third-party_library)) is:

In your project directory (the one with `app.yaml`):

```
$ mkdir lib
$ pip install -t lib/ httplib2
```

Then create a new file named `appengine_config.py` in the same directory:

```
# appengine_config.py
vendor.add('lib')
```

If you have multiple third party dependencies, but their names in a requirements.txt and then use

```
pip install -t lib/ -r requirements.txt
```